# I would like to plot a graph with polarization curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, graphs

I would like to plot functions like that, can you help me please?

[image]

Comment: You can do this using the `tikz` package. It will require some `path`s and `nodes`. Check the pgf-tikz manual for more information. The most complicated part of the figure is probably the curve itself, I suggest using a Bezier-curve for this.

Comment: You are also more likely to receive helpful answers, if you show us, what you have already tried in a minimal working example and/or ask a more specific question concerning something in a piece of code that does not work in the way you intended it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: polarization curve]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %\draw[help lines] (-2,-4) grid (10,4);
        \draw[-latex] (-2,0) -- (10,0) node[above]{$E(V)$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above]{$i(\text{A}) \text{ ou } j_s(\text{A}²\cdot m^{-2})$};
        
        \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=2pt,label=below right:{$E_{\text{Nernest}}$}] at (5,0) {};
        
        \draw[red,line width=1pt] (1,-3) to[out=80,in=180,looseness=1.5] (5,0) to[out=0,in=-100,looseness=1.5] (9,3);
        
        \node at (1.2,-2) {Red $\longleftarrow$ Ox};
        \node at (8.8,2) {Red $\longrightarrow$ Ox};
        
        \node[draw,red,rounded corners=3pt,line width=1.5pt,inner sep=5pt,anchor=south] at (4,-4) {Système lent};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I recycled parts of your code.

Comment: Thank you very much, perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `pgfplots` approach using `y=tan(x)`. I did not micromanage the placement of the nodes (I am not patient enough).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}

\begin{document}

% Based on http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/example_323.tex (had to add deg(x))
% See http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    restrict y to domain = -10:10,
    samples = 1000,
    width = 100mm, 
    height = 50mm,
    xmin = -1, 
    xmax = 6,
    ticks = none, % uncomment to see ticks
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = center,
    xlabel = {$E(V)$},
    ylabel = {$i(A)$ ou $j_s$},
    ]
\addplot[red, domain=0.5*pi:1.5*pi] {tan(deg(x))};
% Stolen from SebGlav's answer :)
\node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=2pt,label=below right:{$E_{\text{Nernest}}$}] at (3.14,0) {};
\node at (1.5,-5) {Red $\longleftarrow$ Ox};
\node at (5,5) {Red $\longrightarrow$ Ox};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update

After SebGlav's comment, I played with `restrict y to domain = -30:30,` to better match the requested look.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}

\begin{document}

% Based on http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/example_323.tex
% See http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    restrict y to domain = -30:30,
    samples = 1000,
    width = 100mm, 
    height = 50mm,
    xmin = -1, 
    xmax = 6,
    ticks = none,
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = center,
    xlabel = {$E(V)$},
    ylabel = {$i(A)$ ou $j_s$},
    ]
\addplot[red, domain=0.5*pi:1.5*pi] {tan(deg(1*x))};
% Stolen from SebGlav's answer :)
\node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=2pt,label=below right:{$E_{\text{Nernest}}$}] at (3.14,0) {};
\node at (1.5,-15) {Red $\longleftarrow$ Ox};
\node at (4.5,10) {Red $\longrightarrow$ Ox};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great too, but I feel like the tangent should be horizontal on E.

Comment: @SebGlav You are right. I did not pay enough attention to that!

Comment: @SebGlav I tried to address your comment in an update. Overall, your solution seems easier.

Comment: Many thanks, very happy to your contribution.